# How to only get the time interval from a series of datetime values in pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, datetime, plsql

I have a column of type date (datetime) in a table. The table is inserted one row daily with this column as inserting date time. Now I want to check the time when it normally gets updated, i.e., I want to get the time interval during the day (MIN(ONLY_TIME_PART) and MAX(ONLY_TIME_PART)).

How should I do that?

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name do you mean the MAX/MIN part? That's just pseudo code to show that I want to get the time interval from a series of date time values whose date parts are different. In SQL Server I can use Time datatype but it doesn't seem to exist in PL/SQL

Comment: PL/SQL is only for stored procedures, that's why I was asking for that. If you just want a query, that is SQL, not PL/SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see your point although I am still confused because I am a newbie. I know that PL/SQL specific part (the procedural statements) are for PL/SQL engine to process, but what about the the normal SQL part? The normal SQL engine takes care of it? But anyway, I just have one column of type date, and I want to find the time interval during the day, even though the values are in different dates, how should I do that?

Comment: Please show example data. just subtract the two to get an interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a compelling reason to use PL/SQL, I'd recommend using just plain (Oracle) SQL, which is sufficient to:

- Extract the hour and minute components of a timestamp using [TO_CHAR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm)
- Convert time units to a standardized time interval with [NUMTODSINTERVAL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions103.htm)
- Perform comparison (min/max) among a table full of intervals
- Perform arithmetic (difference) on particular intervals

For example:

```
WITH
daily_updates AS ( --My synthetic 100-record impression of your date table
  SELECT level                                 AS entry_number
       , SYSDATE + level + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE/2 AS insertion_timestamp
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level<100),
update_times AS ( --Conversion of dates to times-since-midnight
  SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL(TO_CHAR(insertion_timestamp,'MI'),'MINUTE')  --Extract minutes from date/time, and convert to time interval
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL(TO_CHAR(insertion_timestamp,'HH24'),'HOUR')  --Extract hours from date/time, and convert to time interval
         AS tsm --Sum of hour and minute components: TSM (Time Since Midnight)
  FROM daily_updates)
SELECT max(tsm)-min(tsm) AS time_range   --The part you're looking for
     , min(tsm)          AS earliest_TSM --In case you're curious
     , max(tsm)          AS latest_TSM   --What the min/max TSMs are
FROM update_times
```

If you *really* have your heart set on PL/SQL, however, you could loop a cursor over all the entries, doing essentially the same calculation but without taking advantages of the optimizations the SQL engine does behind the scenes. Also, you have to track down the [built-in INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i54330). You'd end up with something like:

```
DECLARE 
  FUNCTION get_time_span(verbose IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL) 
    RETURN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
  IS
    CURSOR date_entries
      IS SELECT insertion_timestamp 
      FROM daily_updates;  --Your date table here
    min_TSM     INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;
    max_TSM     INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;
    current_TSM INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;
  BEGIN
    FOR entry IN date_entries LOOP
      current_TSM := NUMTODSINTERVAL(TO_CHAR(entry.insertion_timestamp, 'MI'), 'MINUTE')
                   + NUMTODSINTERVAL(TO_CHAR(entry.insertion_timestamp, 'HH24'), 'HOUR');
      IF min_TSM IS NULL OR current_TSM < min_TSM THEN
        min_TSM := current_TSM;
      END IF;
      IF max_TSM IS NULL OR current_TSM > max_TSM THEN
        max_TSM := current_TSM;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN max_TSM - min_TSM;
  END get_time_span;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The time span is '||get_time_span());
END;
```